# Docker environmental variables sharing

Tags: docker

It seems it is not possible to use the environment variables created by a specific process in a docker container by another process in the same container. Can someone please confirm that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relationship between the processes. There is nothing special about environment variables in container processes. The entrypoint/"container root" process gets an environment with link- and custom variables but that's it. Otherwise the general rules apply. Child processes inherent environment from their parents.

Comment: I am trying to access the environment variables created by the 'entrypoint' process in another process inside the same container which is not a child process. My entrypoint process is a django runserver process which starts the container(web). This container is linked to a postgres db container (via link). Now in my host I am running PyCharm to debug the remote django app. PyCharm starts a separate django runserver process (using remote python interpreter on the web container) but fails to connect to the db container even if I pass the db container specific env variables to the debugger.

Comment: A process created by the entrypoint process is its child and does inherit a copy of its parent's environment upon creation. Hardly possible to tell what's going wrong in your scenario.